# What are the differences between .Net Control Methods GetChildIndex and IndexOf

Tags: .net, vb.net

I am unable to find when these values are different in my code.  Each returns the same Integer value for the control I am referencing.  What are the differences between these two?  Both methods take in as a parameter a Control Object and both provide an Index.  IN all my uses the same index is being return for the same Control.

**Child Ctrl Index:** [MSDN Controls.GetChildIndex](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-US/dotnet/api/system.windows.forms.control.controlcollection.getchildindex?view=netframework-4.7.2&viewFallbackFrom=xamarinandroid-7.1)

> Me.Controls.GetChildIndex(Control)

**Ctrl Index:** [MSDN Controls.IndexOf](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.windows.forms.control.controlcollection.indexof?redirectedfrom=MSDN&view=netframework-4.7.2)

> Me.Controls.IndexOf(Control)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As the documentation clearly states, `GetChildIndex` throws an exception if the item is not found while `IndexOf` does not.  You have to call the overload of `GetChildIndex` with two parameters and pass `False` as the second argument for `GetChildIndex` to behave like `IndexOf`.

Comment: Perfect .  That much I saw however I was actually confused by the mention of Contol vs 'Child' Contol and wanted to make sure there wasn't some possibility where the index returned would be different between the two. Easy enough thanks.

Comment: It's worth noting that `IndexOf` is a member of the `IList` interface so any type that implements `IList` is obliged to implement `IndexOf`.  `GetChildIndex`, on the other hand, is specific to the `Control.ControlCollection`.  There was presumably some reason that they decided to add the dedicated method and it may well have had something to do with the second overload, which no other `IndexOf` method would have.

Comment: That's excellent information thank you.  Where would I find that information?  Is it in the MSDN links I provided and perhaps I missed it?

Comment: Not directly.  You have to look around a bit more, which I have done over the years.  The documentation for the `Control.ControlColection` does specify that it implements `IList` and the documentation for `IList` specifies that `IndexOf` is a member.

Answer (score 1):

The only difference is that GetChildIndex will throw an exception if the control is not found. Internally, [GetChildIndex](https://referencesource.microsoft.com/#System.Windows.Forms/winforms/Managed/System/WinForms/Control.cs,edfad0ccd084fddf) uses IndexOf. Any further discussion as to why the two methods exist is a matter of opinion and would thus be off-topic (not allowed here).